# Download Files within iPhone app

Tags: iphone, pdf, file, uiwebview

I am currently developing an iPhone app and would like to implement the ability to download files (specifically pdf, mp3, doc and ppt files) from the internet. I have created the UIWebView, but want to know the best way of capturing the files when they are linked to in the webview and then download them to a specified folder in the documents directory.

Any advice/links to tutorials etc would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have found the method for capturing links. It's a delegate method, so make sure that all of the hooks are in place:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *URL = [request URL]; 
        NSLog(@"url is: %s ", URL);
    }   
    return YES;   
}
```

[From here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37140-need-help-grabbing-url-clicked-link-inside-uiwebview.html)

Will post my final code once I'm done.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**
UIWebView can not be used to *download* pdf, mp3, doc, ppt, etc... It is used to display only webpage.

You need to use [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) to draw pdf document. You need [Media Player framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952) to to play songs, audio books.

To download a file from the server, you can try to use [NSData initWithContentsOfURL] method.

An example:

```
NSString *strImagePathURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://foo.com/%d.png", item];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImagePathURL]];
```

You can later decide what to do with NSData, you can save it to file on the Documents folder using the [NSData writeToFile] method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if you read the question I ask how to download them from the internet using the UIWebView. The question was more a case of how to capture links to files with the stated file extensions.

Comment: Also you can handle mp3s and pdfs in a UIWebView.

Comment: hi Jack, if you want to download the files of specific types, you still need to handle yourself. From what I know, saving files in Safari is impossible. You can capture the links that user click and create the NSData to download them manually.

Answer (score 1):

1. To capture links in a UIWebView, implement the [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) delegate method, and return `NO` when you see a link you want to handle.
2. For example code on how to download using HTTP on the iPhone, see the [SimpleURLConnections](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/index.html) sample project.